# Autohotkey: Can't figure out why this is pushing Shift along with the rest of the code

Tags: autohotkey, shift

I am trying to make a macro that will repeat hitting O and M as long as i have my side mouse button held down, but all of a sudden now it is also hitting shift. Any idea why or how to fix it?

```
delaybetweenfkeys:=0
fkeydowndelay:=5

XButton1::
Down := True
Send, {O Down}{m Down}
Loop
{
Send, {O Down}{m Down}
Sleep, 5
Send, {O Up}{m Up}
If !Down
  Break
}
Send, {O Up}{m Up}
Return
XButton1 Up::Down := False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling it to send a capital 'O', and to achieve that, it sends Shift+o.  So if you have some other key being pressed in the meantime, it will get shifted as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! Makes total sense didn't even think of that.

Comment: @Armin: How do you propose Autohotkey sends a capital 'O' if it doesn't send Shift? The purpose of `Send` is to send **keystrokes**, not characters. The documentation even says that `!A` includes a Shift press whereas `!a` does not. And if that doesn't satisfy you, do some testing. I came to my conclusion because I tried OP's code (my mouse doesn't have `XButton1` so I used `RButton` instead) and observed that holding down both 'a' and the right mouse button resulted in some capital 'A's being generated.